# Error ball.lua:20: bad argument #5 to 'rectangle' (number expected, got nil)

Tags: lua, draw, game-development, love2d

im making a pong game but love is giving me an error

```
ball = {}

function ball:load()
    self.x = love.graphics.getWidth() /2 
    self.y = love.graphics.getHeight() /2 
    self.width = 20
    self.hieght = 20
    self.speed = 200 
    self.xvel = -self.speed
    self.yvel = 0
end 

function ball:update(dt)
    self:move(dt)
end

function ball:draw()
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
end

function ball:move(dt)
    self.x = self.x + self.xvel * dt
    self.y = self.y + self.yvel * dt
end
```

Comment: you assigned `self.hieght` but use `self.height`  hence `self.height` is a nil value and not `20` please through your code carefully befor asking people for help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

you misspelled `self.height`

try this:

```
function ball:load() 
    self.x = love.graphics.getWidth() /2 
    self.y = love.graphics.getHeight() /2 
    self.width = 20
    self.height = 20
    self.speed = 200 
    self.xvel = -self.speed
    self.yvel = 0
end
```